# Why do I get wrong and different navigator.getPreferredLanguage, navigator.getLocaleName and navigator.language in a cordova app with IOS 10.2?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, locale

When I execute an app inside the iphone 6 plus simulator with IOS 10.2, I get following results when trying to detect language (from the safari inspector web against the simulator's app webview) :

[image: navigator language detection in ios]

The iphone settings are like these:

[image: ios settings]

So I was expecting "es-ES" as the preferredLanguage and navigator.language, but I get "en-ES".

If I execute the navigator.language with the inspector web against a clean safari window inside the simulator, I get "es-ES" correctly.

If I execute the same against another image of the simulator (iphone 5 with IOS 10.2) I get the proper results. I don't want to reset the simulator image, as some customers are complaining about similar behaviour, and is the only way of reproducing it. I have a physical iphone 5s with ios 10, and it is not happening to me.

Any ideas of what could it be happening?

cordova version 5.3.3 with ios 3.9.2.
iOS platform: Xcode 8.2.1, Build version 8C1002

Comment: try this: var language = navigator.languages ? navigator.languages[0] : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage);

Comment: navigator.languages == undefined :(